# Unity large,dynamic tile map

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm thinking of making city transport simulation game, based on tile map like simcity. Because transportation is the main component, I'm not gonna describe city thoroughly, like drawing all the buildings or others. But I need to divide the city to districts and villages.

I want them to be generated randomly, based on tile map system - Actually this doesn't have to be tile based, but I don't have any better idea to generate randomly divided districts.

The problem is there are literally to many tiles. Of course I won't make all the tiles to GameObjects, but array storing the information of tile just gets like 4000x3000 (for 12,000,000 tiles). Is it okay? I think this will seriously slow down the game.

I searched for many ways to generate tile maps, but those tile maps are for RPGs.. they are just sprites and background.

My tiles should change dynamically(maybe the colors, and I'm making the game with 3d so maybe the tile can have height that may change), with showing the status of that tile(a small region of the city). What will be better way for my needs?

Thank you!

Comment: Think about an image file of 4000x3000 pixels, maybe find how they deal with that amount of data?

Comment: Hi user, you can't ask that here.  This is for code questions.  Go to gamedev.com and you'll get a great answer within hours.

Comment: Hi @Catwood.  That is totally unrelated.  Unity3D has (obviously) entire systems and assets related to tile-based games; it is a game engine.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you should generate a mesh to represent your tiles. This will allow you to represent a large number of tiles as a single game object.

It is not as troublesome as it sounds. I actually went through this myself recently, and have written a step-by-step guide on how to do it, and how to solve a host of other issues I ran in to working with tiles:

http://matthewlynch.net/2017/02/19/efficient-artefact-free-2d-tile-mapping-in-unity-5-5/

The only caveat I would mention (this is discussed in the tutorial, but not directly addressed) is that you should still divide your map up in some way.

I would not recommend exceeding 100x100 tiles in a single mesh, and in fact would recommend breaking it up even further. But once you get the basics of tile->mesh rendering up and running, this is not difficult to do.

Comment: You blokes really need to learn about and work with occlusion culling, which is a major and central part of working with 3D engines. (Occlusion culling is, of course, completely built-in to Unity; they have the superb, industry-leading occlusion culling).

Comment: Occlusion culling is the strong argument for rendering the tiles to meshes.

Unity (and the graphics engine below it) will cull objects and even vertices that are not visible, but that is only part of the picture. There is still overhead for maintaining the Unity game objects in the tree. Even if you disable the game objects in the tree, there is still overhead.

It is pretty easy to see. Put 10,000 sprites (as separate game objects) in a Unity scene and look at the performance. It plummets. Even if only a few hundred are visible.

Comment: Occlusion culling is also why I would recommend not creating a 100x100 tile mesh, but breaking it up to more sensible portions representative of how many tiles can fit on the screen. As advance as occlusion culling algorithms are, its always faster and more efficient if the entire object can be excluded with a simple positional check.

Comment: right, it's a commonplace: say you build a large car racetrack.  It's SOP that you have to break it up in to chunks, so your occlusion culling works.   the engineering involved is figuring out on the fly what size chunks to do, that run. ("excluded with a simple positional check" - you don't have to do that; the OC is better than us.  it does that in a mathematically optimal way as a first pass.)

Comment: Yep definitely. Sorry, I should have been clearer. I wasn't suggesting manual positional checks for disabling. Just that by breaking it up in to more manageable chunks the inbuilt OC will have an easier time.

Comment: Not sure if it is because unity has been updated, but the tute pointed to by this link, creates several errors!

Comment: It looks like the link in this answer is dead. [Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20170426141709/http://matthewlynch.net/2017/02/19/efficient-artefact-free-2d-tile-mapping-in-unity-5-5/) a link to the archived article.